# DatetimeIndex cannot perform the operation median for pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I see an error of "DatetimeIndex cannot perform the operation median" when computing a series median.
Is there a suggestion on this? Thanks.

Repro code is below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': pd.date_range("2012", periods=3, freq='D')}) 
df['a'].median() 
...
TypeError: DatetimeIndex cannot perform the operation median
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible only if convert column to native unix times format, get median and convert back to datetime:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': pd.date_range("2012", periods=3, freq='D')}) 
m = np.median(df['a'].to_numpy().astype(np.int64)) 
print (pd.Timestamp(m))
2012-01-02 00:00:00
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['a'].to_numpy().astype(np.int64))
[1325376000000000000 1325462400000000000 1325548800000000000]
```

Another idea, thank you @cs95:

```
print (pd.Timestamp(df['a'].astype(np.int64).median()))
2012-01-02 00:00:00
```

Comment: `pd.Timestamp(df['a'].astype(int).median())`?

Comment: @cs95 - I got `TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [int32]`

Comment: @cs95 - I think it seems pandas version dependent, for me working `np.int64` instead `int`

Comment: So int64 works but not int? It might be enhancements in 1.1 (which I'm using).

Comment: Follow-up: why not working for Series median, but works well for pandas median?

Comment: @susanne - Because both are converted to `int64`, first solution is using numpy, second by uning pandas. Principe is same.